# How to treat Queensland itch?

Tags: health, medicines, parasites, horses, allergies

My horse has [Queensland itch](https://kb.rspca.org.au/how-can-i-take-care-of-my-horse-with-queensland-itch_481.html). I'm looking for a range of options to treat it. I'm concerned about the use of poisonous chemicals.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to treat the symptoms or the cause?  Your link suggests midge control is the key.  You might look into 'diatomaceous earth' it is a popular 'natural' treatment.

Comment: @JamesJenkins both. I would need to see evidence . There's a lot of fads out there

Answer (score 3):

I made use of what I had in hand for the first day. 
I've used calamine lotion on the first day to help relieve the itch. Combined with a homemade fly repellent and antiseptic remedy consisting of baby oil, tea tree oil, eucalyptus oil and citronella. I then rugged her with a combo rug, to cover her neck and body. It's also important to rug over the oil application as it can cause the skin to burn in the sun.

I bought and then applied a diluted solution of a [permethrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permethrin) based insect repellent. Continued with the home made oil based fly repellent as an antiseptic and to soothe the skin. I also applied a zinc based lotion to help protect the open sores. I also applied a fly mask to protect her ears and [poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poll_(livestock)). I've ordered her a complete combo rug with a hood to completely protect her from midges.

I will continue with the permethrin solution daily for 7 days then apply weekly to help keep the midges off her. I'll continue to apply the zinc cream mix while there's open wounds and keep her rugged while the weather is hot and insects are out.

I'll re-apply the baby oil insect repellent twice a week. Concentrating on her mane and tail where she is particularly irritated and the skin has been rubbed.

Her condition has cleared up immensely with the treatment.

Improvement

[image]

Applying zinc cream mix

[image]

Working the zinc through the mane to reach the skin.

[image]

Cleo in her new rug.

[image] Note the loose strap under her belly was tightened after taking this pic.

Next season I will try and catch any signs of Queensland itch early and rug her. I don't like to rug them unless absolutely necessary as rugs increase the likelihood of accidental injuries.